Necessary condition for sum of floating point numbers x + y to be x
In my numerical analysis text book there is this problem

Assume a machine with base $\beta$, and $p$ mantissa digits, and that $u$ is the round-off error of a particular number. The number $∣x∣=(0.d_1\dots d_p)_ββ^e$ is representable in the machine. Define:
$$
a(x)=\frac{β^{−1}}{(0.d_1\dots d_p)_β},
$$
If (1): $0 < \frac{t}{|x|}<a(x) u$ and
(2): $\beta^{-1}<\frac{\beta^{-1}}{1-\beta^{-p}} \leq a(x) \leq 1$
show that $fl(x+t)=x$.

My main idea was proving that $t$ is samller than a certain bound, e.g. $t < \frac{\beta^{e-p}}{2}$ but (2) isn't necessary for proving this which makes me doubt my solution + the equality should hold when the machine chop (assuming $x$ is negative) instead of rounding and it doesn't work this way. Any help or hint into the right direction is appreciated.

If the exponent difference is larger than the dp exponent than the value y will not impact x.
